# How to separate values in a column and add them in a new row?

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follow:

```
col1    col2
a        1,2,3
b        ["1","2"]
c        4
```

I want the output as:

```
col1     col2
a1         1
a2         2
a3         3
b1         1
b2         2
c          4
```

Is it possible to do so in R? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you really think this question is warranted after your previous one?

Comment: @Henrik I didn't check his previous posts before I posted the answer.  But, after checking I think it is slightly different that it needs to paste a sequence column with `col1`.  Yes, it is similar as most of the questions that are repeatedly asked.

Comment: @akrun, they are apparently not patient enough to wait 20 minutes :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto  It happened with some other questions where I answered too.  They will post a followup question while I am away, and if they don't get an answer within 10-20 min, will post another thread.  But, I had seen people discouraging followup questions and to be asked as a separate one.  So, I am not sure whether the OP is correct or not.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I didn't mean to offend anyone, I am new to the community and am not very familiar with its code of conduct. I appreciate your concern and will keep this in mind for the future. As for this question, I was actually short on time, a lot of my work was stuck because of this small thing I couldn't understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(transform(df1, col2= gsub('\\[|\\]|"', '', col2)), 'col2', ',', 'long')[
 ,col1:= if(.N>1) paste0(col1, 1:.N) else col1, col1]
#    col1 col2
#1:   a1    1
#2:   a2    2
#3:   a3    3
#4:   b1    1
#5:   b2    2
#6:    c    4
```

Or using `base R`

```
df2 <- stack(setNames(strsplit(gsub('[^0-9,]', '', df1$col2), ','), df1$col1))

df2$ind <-  with(df2, paste0(ind,ave(seq_along(ind), ind, 
    FUN= function(x) if(length(x)==1) '' else seq_along(x))))
colnames(df2) <- paste0('col', 2:1)
```

Comment: @NadeemHussain  Thanks, made some modification to match the expected output